# Solve a differential equation : m*(dv/dt)=-m g - r v

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this differential equation:

$$ m*(dv/dt)=-m g- r v$$

where m, r and g are constants.

I am trying to rewrite the equation as dv=dt form, but I do not know how to do it. I get the solution from the mathematica as

$$ (mg/r+v)*e^{(-rt/m)}-(mg/r)$$

Comment: What do you mean by $dv=dt$ form? Separation of variables?

Comment: I want write the left hand part only related to v and right hand part only related to t and then take integration of both part.

Comment: So, your differential equation is equivalent to $m\,dv=-(mg+rv)\,dt$. Now try to move the dependence on $v$ to the left-hand side.

Comment: @JiDaoyuan Is my edit helpful?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks @ Narasimham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m\left(\frac{dv}{dt}\right)=-mg-rv $$
$$\frac{m \cdot dv}{mg+rv}=-dt $$
Let $u = v + \frac{mg}{r}$, then $du = dv$,the equation turns to:
$$\frac{du}{u}=-\frac{r}{m}dt $$

Answer (score -1):

$$ m*(dv/dt)=-m g- r v$$

$$ dv/dt = -  v * r/m - g $$

Variables are separated, you can now see how negative exponential exponent comes by integrating...

Comment: I downvoted because it provides nothing more (maybe even less) than the other answer here. If you make the answer better..I will rectify the down vote (as I hate given them)!

Comment: I had a sense he got problem at takeoff itself, so better to repeat the starting point. But it is ok..